# Is there a way to look at all OSM tags in one geographical location?

Tags: openstreetmap

I would like to filter locations by a specific OSM tag but I am not sure what OSM tags exist to describe this location. It consists of places where aggregate (sand, gravel) is stored. I looked at tagFinder and taginfo listed here https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags

Basically I know which geographical point I want to look at and I want to know how OSM tags that place. I will then use overpass turbo to create the query.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I have found a solution but there are no features/tags for aggregates and gravel industries. Is there another data source where I could find such information, preferably worldwide? Something like OSM tags?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you can query features, by right-clicking on the button with the arrow and question mark, then clicking on a place and select "query features".
https://www.openstreetmap.org/

It will return nearby features and enclosing features in the panel on the left.